# How to document a closure with phpdocumentor?

Tags: documentation, comments, phpdoc

So, i'm working with Silex microframework and i'm curious about the correct PHPDoc way to document a closure.

```
require_once __DIR__.'/silex.phar'; 

$app = new Silex\Application(); 

$app->get('/hello/{name}', function($name) use($app) { 
    return 'Hello '.$app->escape($name); 
}); 

$app->run();
```

How do i document the GET closure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is it that you are wanting to say to the reader of your document with regard to that closure?  Do you want to highlight that it exists, or create a @uses<-->@usedby documentation link to the Silex\Application->escape() method that your closure is using?

I'm not aware that any PHPDoc syntax exists to document a closure (yet), but given that it can't actually be used by a consumer in an API context, I'm not sure there's a use case to document it... well, aside from providing details to a code-reading doc reader.  If the latter is the case, I'd probably use an @internal tag to write whatever notes about the closure that I wanted the reader to be aware of.  Further, given that I see no "documentable elements" in that code snippet, you'd have to put that @internal tag in the file-level docblock.